# How to define own WebElement in JDI test framework

Tags: jdiframework

I need to define own UI WebElement in JDI test automation framework. For example I need the following elements:

- table with Sortable columns
- table with pagination
- Dropdown with items filtering

How to define them using JDI style and approach?

Answer (score 0):

See examples here

https://github.com/epam/JDI/tree/master/Java/Tests/jdi-uitest-tutorialtests/src/main/java/com/epam/jdi/site/epam/CustomElements

Generally you just extends existing element e.g. dropdown and add your actions or override actions that have new behavior
If you have more details on it. Fill free to ask